# Уходит в рекурсию scanf

Tags: c

При введении символа уходит в рекурсию, нужно что бы считала только числа, как избежать рекурсии в данном коде

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void startMenu(){ //В нем выдается стартовое меню

    printf("---------------------Main Menu---------------------\n");
    printf("This is the phone book of the company 'YptRemont'\n");
    printf("What do you want to do?\n");
    printf("1. View book\n");
    printf("2. Find by ...\n");
    printf("3. Book editor\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
    printf("---------------------Main Menu---------------------\n");

    getsVvod(); //вызом метода ввода
}

void getsVvod(){

    int vvod;
    char str[80];

    scanf("%d", &vvod); //Считываем ввод пользователя
    if (vvod == 1)      //если ввод равен 1 то вызываем метод ViewBook
    {
        ViewBook();
    }
    else if (vvod == 2) //если ввод равен 2 то вызываем метод FindBy
    {
        FindBy();
    }
    else if (vvod == 3) //если ввод равен 3 то вызываем метод BookEditor
    {
        BookEditor();
    }
    else if (vvod == 4) //если ввод равен 4 то вызываем метод Exit
    {
        Exit();
    }
    else // Если не одна из функция не сработала вывод "Ошибки" и  запуск метода заново
    {
        printf("\n \n \nI do not know such a team, return\n \n \n");
        startMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",str, vvod);` - никакой `vvod` вы здесь не читаете...

Comment: Там опечатка, там `scanf("%d", &vvod)` должно быть

Comment: а еще у `scanf` необходимо проверять возвращаемое значение чтобы определить, сколько там реально считалось

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте результат `scanf`, а неверный ввод сбрасывайте... Что-то типа

```
while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
```

или

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
```

или

```
scanf("%*c");
```

Если вы ввели не число - введенное остается в буфере и будет постоянно мешать при очередном вызове...

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий ответ частично верный ... при использовании именно `sscanf()` надо неверный ввод сбрасывать. Но рекурсия возникает еще и потому, что у вас она явно указана: `startMenu() -> getsVvod() -> startMenu()` .... и.т.д. Надо убрать вызов `startMenu()` из `getsVvod()`

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LOOP_MENU   1
#define LOOP_QUIT   2

void ViewBook()     { printf("Call: ViewBook\n"); }
void FindBy()       { printf("Call: FindBy\n"); }
void BookEditor()   { printf("Call: BookEditor\n"); }
void Exit()         { printf("Call: Exit\n"); }

void getsVvod();

void startMenu(){ //В нем выдается стартовое меню

 do {
    printf("---------------------Main Menu---------------------\n");
    printf("This is the phone book of the company 'YptRemont'\n");
    printf("What do you want to do?\n");
    printf("1. View book\n");
    printf("2. Find by ...\n");
    printf("3. Book editor\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
    printf("---------------------Main Menu---------------------\n");
 } while (getsVvod() != LOOP_QUIT); //вызом метода ввода
}

void getsVvod(){

    int vvod, ret;

    //Считываем ввод пользователя
    if ((ret = scanf("%d", &vvod)) != 1) {
        printf("Bad input\n");
        while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');    
        return(LOOP_MENU);
    }
    
    switch (vvod) {
    case 1:  ViewBook();
        break;
    case 2: FindBy();
        break;
    case 3: BookEditor();
        break;
    case 4: Exit();
        return(LOOP_QUIT);
    default:
        printf("\n \n \nI do not know such a team, return\n \n \n");
    }
    return(LOOP_MENU);

}
 
int main () {
    startMenu();
}
```